# Trying to add scala-uri plugin to play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala-2.10

I'm trying to use the following library in my play application: https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri

I've added it to ./build.sbt as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.netaporter" %% "scala-uri" % "0.4.0",
  ...
```

However I get the following errors:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.github.scct#scct_2.10;0.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-pgp:0.8.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.scct#scct_2.10;0.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I know it doesn't help you, but I definitely recommend not to use SCCT and to use Scoverage instead: https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuck, sorry. Neither of those should be runtime dependencies for `scala-uri`.

I have just pushed a new version `0.4.1`. Could you give that a try? They are no longer appearing in the [0.4.1 pom file](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/netaporter/scala-uri_2.10/0.4.1/scala-uri_2.10-0.4.1.pom) as opposed to the [0.4.0 pom file](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/netaporter/scala-uri_2.10/0.4.0/scala-uri_2.10-0.4.0.pom), so I'm hoping that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this project requires a dependency that it can not find. Maybe you need to add a repository where `com.github.scct#scct_2.10;0.3-SNAPSHOT` can be found. As it seems to be a github project, you could also build it locally yourself.